# Use HTML templates (as files) with Reagent

Tags: html, dom, clojure, reagent

I have a project, which front-end stack has to be based on ClojureScript and React (through Reagent, not Om or other libs).

Additionally, I have a large amount of HTML templates (as .html files) from designer, who knows nothing about Clojure, data structures and Hiccup.

Is there any way to have plain HTML files (without translating their content to Hiccup/Reagent structures) and to use Reagent only in some sections on the page?

E.g.:

```
// html file structure

<section_1>
<section_2>
....
<section_9>
<section_10>
....
<section_17>
<section_18>
```

All sections in this template are static except `section_9` and `section_10`.

Can I have all static sections stored somewhere as plain .html (for example, somewhere in /resources) but render dynamic sections as reagent/react components?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [kioo](https://github.com/ckirkendall/kioo/) which is based on [enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive)

Comment: I have requirements to use only Reagent. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Kioo is a library to be used with reagent

Comment: I mistakenly thought kioo is the separate lib to work with React.
Thank you one more time.